# Save Created XML file with save dialogue box

Tags: c#, xml

I have used xmltextwriter to create xml file and saved on development D: drive. now i want to allow user with dialogue box to save file at desired location.

thanks

Comment: below is code 
xmlFileName = "EFIX.036003.CMF.FIX."+sDate+".CMF003.xml";    
   
   XmlTextWriter w = new XmlTextWriter(@"D:\"+xmlFileName, Encoding.UTF8);
   w.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify the environment, here a code snippet for WinForms:

```
static class Example
{
    public static XmlTextWriter GetWriterForFolder(string fileName, Encoding encoding)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog dlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
            return null;

        XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(Path.Combine(dlg.SelectedPath, fileName), encoding);
        writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

        return writer;
    }

    public static XmlTextWriter GetWriterForFile(Encoding encoding)
    {
        SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
        dlg.Filter = "XML Files (*.xml)|*.xml";

        if (dlg.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
            return null;

        XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(dlg.FileName, encoding);
        writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

        return writer;
    }
}
```

The `GetWriterForFolder` function lets the user to select a folder where file will be saved, you have to provide a file name as parameter. Like this:

```
string fileName = "EFIX.036003.CMF.FIX." + sDate + ".CMF003.xml";
XmlTextWriter writer = Example.GetWriterForFolder(fileName, Encoding.UTF8);
```

The `GetWriterForFile` function let the user select a folder and the file name to use. Like this:

```
XmlTextWriter writer = Example.GetGetWriterForFile(Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: thanks @ adriano for your reply
can you tell me in web application on button click how can i show save dialog box to user
below is my code on button click

xmlFileName = "EFIX.036003.CMF.FIX."+sDate+".CMF003.xml";    
   
   XmlTextWriter w = new XmlTextWriter(@"D:\"+xmlFileName, Encoding.UTF8);
   w.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;   
   
   w.WriteStartDocument();
   w.WriteStartElement("Document");
   w.WriteAttributeString("xmlns:xsi","http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance");
w.WriteEndElement();
   w.WriteEndDocument();    
   w.Close();

Comment: In a web application? Tag your question with ASP.NET! It's **really** different! Plain ASP.NET? MVC? The server should provide an URL to create the file and the user can click a link (or a LinkButton) to download the file and save it in local.

Comment: hi all, i have used httpresponse to fix my issue. after creating xml i have used httpresponse with content type text/xml
thanks all